# Regex pattern match in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I want to know the preg_match condition in PHP to check if a string starts with a month (January to December) and ends with a colon (:). In between, it can have any alphabet, character or number. Can someone please help? Stuck for an hour, not getting the right results.

For example, the string `"December 2,&*&98hkjk:"` should return true.

I got the pattern for Month and Colon using txt2re.com but I am having no clue how to form it and test the result.

```
$txt='May k!ur2!3:';

  $re1='((?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Sept|Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dec(?:ember)?))';   # Month 1
  $re2='.*?';   # Non-greedy match on filler
  $re3=':'; # Uninteresting: c
  $re4='.*?';   # Non-greedy match on filler
  $re5='(:)';   # Any Single Character 1

  if ($c=preg_match_all ("/".$re1.$re2.$re3.$re4.$re5."/is", $txt, $matches))
  {
      $month1=$matches[1][0];
      $c1=$matches[2][0];
      echo "Matched \n";
  }
  else { echo "No match"; }
```

GOT THE SOLUTION:

```
$txt=$_POST['wtfb'];
        $re1='((?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Sept|Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dec(?:ember)?))'; # Month 1
        $re4='.*?'; # Non-greedy match on filler
        $re5='(:)'; # Any Single Character 1

        if ($c=preg_match_all ("/".$re1.$re4.$re5."/is", $txt, $matches))
        {
            $month1=$matches[1][0];
            $c1=$matches[2][0];
            echo 'Match';
        }
        else 
        { 
            echo 'No match'; 
        }
```

Comment: Show your attempt(s). Ask what you are stuck on specifically.

Comment: Please post the regex pattern you have tried.

Comment: `$re3` and `$re5` both match the colon character, so it will only match when there are two colons. Your example only has one colon.

Comment: $res4 and $res5 seem redundant

Comment: Why are you using `preg_match_all` if you're only looking for one match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [strpos](http://php.net/strpos) to check a word in string.

```
$str = "December 2,&*&98hkjk:";

//Check for `December`
if(strpos($str, 'December') !== false) { // use === for type comparison 
   //do your stuff
    echo 'Match';
}else{
    echo 'No Match';
}
```

`strpos()` in much simpler solution for this.

> This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function.

Comment: So 12 "if" conditions + lowercased scenarios ?

Comment: if case doesn't matter you can `if(strpos( strtolower($str), 'december') !== false)` and always pass lowercase

Comment: Dont know how to do in php, but i would create an array of months and for each loop them in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You want a pattern like this (incomplete, add the remaining months in ...):

```
"/^(January|February|March|...|December).*:$/"
```

Note I added the beginning and end of string anchors `^` and `$` because you said the string begins with a month and ends with a colon. But your use of `preg_match_all` is a little confusing, if you need to match multiples of this same pattern in one string then this is not the correct solution.